# Make it ask me for my ssh passphrase again?

Tags: macos, password, unix, ssh, encryption

I am trying to disable all password logins except for that through my ssh key. However now any time I ssh into my server, it just logs in automatically and doesn't prompt me for my ssh decryption passphrase anymore. How can I get it to "forget" and ask me again?

Comment: Please add your system version...by editing your question!

Comment: Your question has already been answered in https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/142463/terminal-wont-ask-for-passphrase-and-not-stored-in-keychain?rq=1